# Eth received minus eth spent does not match eth balance and by a big margin

Tags: etherscan

This address "0xd75e7d1A42b616A24a8AFA71a462D74738a87d50" shows eth balance 0f 3.66. However this address has received 162 eth and spent about 10 eth. The eth balance should be much higher if you look at the internal transactions for this wallet in etherscan. The blockchair explorer summary shows the same confusing information. Link attached

https://blockchair.com/ethereum/address/0xd75e7d1a42b616a24a8afa71a462d74738a87d50

Am I missing something? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the transaction's fees it's been paying above 5 eth per day for the last two weeks, probably the average is 10 eth per day. It does a lot of small transactions to a contract.

From a quick look at the transaction history seems to be a trading bot or something similar, see https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0xd75e7d1a42b616a24a8afa71a462d74738a87d50&p=1.